# Android disable nav drawer indicator

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm using the Navigation Drawer pattern from http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

But now, I want to use my `Activity` icon as burger icon and the **ic_drawer** should be invisible. I can't set the **drawerImageRes** in the constructor of **ActionBarDrawerToggle** (from android.support.v4.app) to 0 (zero). The app crashes.

Comment: What is the error thrown? Why not use the standard drawer icon for the toggle? Your app icon will still be displayed next to it.

Comment: I use now a transparent image.